# Quil on Raspberry Pi

Tags: clojure, raspberry-pi, processing, cider, quil

Has anyone managed to get the default Clojure Quil example (created via "lein new quil my-sketch") working on a Raspberry Pi?

I have installed OpenJDK and have CIDER/emacs up and running on a Raspberry Pi 4. However when I compile the default whirling circle example, the application window opens but is entirely black.  The dimensions (500 x 500) and title ("You spin me right round") display fine, so it seems it is working to some degree.

Any thoughts on what how to troubleshoot would be super, thanks.

Comment: Does it log anything? Maybe it wants to use some OpenGL/EL context, that is not supported?

Comment: hi @cfrick, no nothing is logged, at least in terms of explicit exceptions being thrown. My command of clojurescript is still very basic so I don't know how to interogate any issues via the repl.  Interesting thoughts re. OpenGL, although the Quil example is in 2D and doesnt use OpenGL afaik.  (Can you explain what EL stands for?).